# Python: TLS session with Yubikey

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ssl, pkcs#11, yubico

I am setting up a rest client that must be trusted by a remote server using client certificate. Client written in python, running on windows 10. How can I use **YubiKey 5** to store private key to encrypt SSL connection?

It seems like there is no off-the-shelf solution / python package that supports using pkcs11 for ssl context. 
We were able to use https://github.com/square/ghostunnel with yubikeys with client certificates, but it makes solution less secure and more complicated to deploy.

Comment: FWIW SSL connections are not encrypted with a private key.  A session key is chosen by a key exchange protocol and used with symmetric encryption.  The client certificate and its private key are used for authentication (identity verification) not for encryption.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thank you for the info.
Can one do it in python using pkcs11?